# Python Accessing Specific Dictionary element

Tags: python

I want to access corresponding data index which is desired by user from the Dictionary..
when a user provide a *order no. 2 then the data of index 2 of dictionary is interest of item.. I always get index 1 from for loop...*

```
for key in menuList: // here the problem starts
    menuList={}
    menuList["momo"] = {'id' : 1,'name' : 'MOMO','price':80}
    menuList["pizza"] = {'id' : 2,'name' : 'Pizza','price':180}
    for key in menuList:
        print(str(menuList[key]["id"]) + "\t" + menuList[key]["name"]  + "\t" +  str(menuList[key]["price"]))

    c = 'y'
    orderlist = []
    total = 0
    while(c !='n'):
        sel = input("Order yor food : ")
        for key in menuList:
            if sel == str(menuList[key]["id"]):
                print(menuList[key]["name"]  + "\tRs. " +  str(menuList[key]["price"]))
                orderlist.append(menuList[key])
                total = total + menuList[key]["price"]
                print("Total is ", total)
                c = input("Do you want to order next? 'n for NO else 'YES' otherwise")
                for key in menuList:
                    print(str(menuList[key]["id"]) + "\t" + menuList[key]["name"]  + "\t" +  str(menuList[key]["price"]))
                break
            else:
                print("Food not available!")
                for key in menuList:
                    print(str(menuList[key]["id"]) + "\t"+ menuList[key]["name"]  + "\t" +  str(menuList[key]["price"]))
                c = input("Do you want to order next? 'n for NO else 'YES' otherwise")
                break
    print("\n\nBill :\n")
    i = 1
    if len(orderlist) > 0:
        for item in orderlist:
            print(i)
            i+=1
            print(item["name"], + item["price"])
        print("Total is Rs.", total , "only")
    else:
        print("No any order")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loop enters the else part if the first key is not matching and tells the user that the food is not available.
You might want to replace the `for` loop with a search of the user's input in your `menuList`, like

```py
key = next((key for key in menuList if str(menuList[key]['id']) == sel), None)
if key is not None:
    print(f'found menu {key}')
```

or - better - use the `id` as key of your `menuList`. `next(...)` returns the first element of the iterator in brackets or `None` if there is none...